# How to use useState properly from HOC constructor (implemented by UseMemo)

Tags: reactjs

I have a react function that call the internet, and I want to robustly handle the error from it.

I created HOC componnent:

```
const WithErrorHandling = (WrappedComponnent, axios) => {

const useComponentWillMount = (func) => {
    useMemo(func, [])
}

const WithStateComponent = (props) => {
    const [error, setError] = useState("Error");

    useComponentWillMount(() => {   
        axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res, error => {
            setError(error);
            console.log("[WillMount] Got Error" + error.message);
        });
    });

    return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Modal 
                    show={error}
                    clicked={() => setError(null)}
                >
                    {error ? error.message : "No Error Masage"}
                </Modal>
                <WrappedComponnent {...props}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
}

return WithStateComponent;
```

}

```
export default WithErrorHandling;
```

The reason I don't use here the useEffect is because the internet calls in `WrappedComponnent` are implemented using useEffect, and because of this, my wrapper never run before the `WrappedComponnent` finish mounting, because the error there is before that then if I implement the wraping in useEffect my code will never get called.

Now I have a different problem, it looks like, `setError` not working from my `useComponentWillMount`, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The setError is working fine but you are testing the error message in a  wrong way,remove `console.log("[WillMount] Got Error" + error.message);` from the function.and do it:

```
useEffect(()=>{
if(error)
{
console.log("[WillMount] Got Error" + error.message);
}
},[error])
```